# displaying multiple images serially within a loop

Tags: objective-c, image

I am trying to get a streaming display within a loop.  My understanding is that I could, in principle, hang the program by putting an infinite loop associated with, say, a button push.  In any case, when I run this code, the running counter prints out just fine, and the frames from the camera are captured (I can save them as a series of files.)  However, the display using setImage does nothing until the end of the loop, when it displays the last image on the screen.  My question is this:
If the program runs serially as described in the documentation, why does the display not occur, while the code on other side of the display command processes just fine?  Is the display simply "dumped off" into a parallel process, in which case I should just put a delay loop waiting for the display to complete?

Thanks
WMW

```
uint32 MaxRuns = 10;
for (uint32 NoRuns = 0 ; NoRuns < MaxRuns ; NoRuns++)   
{
//
//Here is some code to capture each image from the camera
//and save them to image.tif
//
inFilePath = @"/Volumes/Portable_Mac/Programming/CameraData/image.tif";
    [TestImage initWithContentsOfFile:inFilePath];      
[viewWindow setImage: TestImage];
    printf("run number:%d\n",NoRuns);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drawing isn't dumped off to another thread, but it is deferred. When you call `setImage:`, the view's `image` ivar gets changed, and most likely the setter also calls [`setNeedsDisplay:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-BBCCADHC). This is how the view signals that it needs to be redrawn. Because drawing is an expensive thing to do, however, it only [gets done once per pass](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH7-SW22) (specifically, at the end) of the run loop, which doesn't happen until your `for` loop ends.

Tthe best way to do show a series of images would almost certainly be a repeating timer ([`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-performSelector_withObject_afterDelay_) is also worth looking at). Load all your images into an array, then start the timer:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.5
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(changeDisplayedImage:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

Then your timer's action will change the view's image:

```
- (void)changeDisplayedImage:(NSTimer *)tim {
    // currImageIdx is an ivar keeping track of our position
    if( currImageIdx >= [imageArray count] ){
        [tim invalidate];
        return;
    }
    [viewWindow setImage:[imageArray objectAtIndex:currImageIdx]];
    currImageIdx++;
}
```

Note that except for the delay from the actual drawing, setting the contents of the view would probably happen so fast you wouldn't see the image. If you *really really* want your view to draw immediately, however, sending it `display` should work (as mentioned in the `setNeedsDisplay:` description).

Comment: Thank you - this is very useful.  I appreciate the thoroughness of your answer.  Ultimately, my objective is to monitor images as they come in from a camera, setting camera characteristics until they are "optimized," then save the appropriate file to disk for later processing.

Comment: my actual code goes like this: 
    NSImage *TestImage = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:inFilePath] autorelease];
    [viewWindow setImage: TestImage];
    [viewWindow display];

I had to reinitialize the NSImage as well as ask the NSImageView to display immediately.  This now works.