# Displaying images in sequence with a loop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiimage

I got an NSArray with 5 pictures. I want to display them one after the other in a loop.
My code :

```
 NSArray *tabImage = [[NSArray alloc] init];

tabImage = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:  
               [UIImage imageNamed:@"picto_1.png"],
               [UIImage imageNamed:@"picto_2.png"],
               [UIImage imageNamed:@"picto_3.png"],
               [UIImage imageNamed:@"picto_4.png"],
               [UIImage imageNamed:@"picto_5.png"],
               nil] retain];

int var = 0;
var = indexPath.row;

for (int var = 0; var < 20; var++) {
    pictoImage.image = [tabImage objectAtIndex:(var % 5)];
}
```

I got the same picture all the time.

Thanks for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [displaying multiple images serially within a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794105/displaying-multiple-images-serially-within-a-loop)

Answer (score 6):

I’m guessing `pictoImage` is an `UIImageView`. In that case look at the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), specifically the `animationImages` properties.

```
 pictoImage.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:  
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"picto_1.png"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"picto_2.png"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"picto_3.png"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"picto_4.png"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"picto_5.png"],
                                   nil];

 // How many seconds it should take to go through all images one time.
 pictoImage.animationDuration = 5.0;

 // How many times to repeat the animation (0 for indefinitely).
 pictoImage.animationRepeatCount = 4;

 [pictoImage startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not giving the framework time to actually render the images to the window.

All your updates are being coalesced into one "setNeedsDisplay" call. On the next iteration of the run loop, the image view will be rendered using the last image that you set in the loop.

Comment: How can i do to print each picture ?

Comment: If by "print" you mean "render to the window", there's a slew of options. If you insist on doing this synchronously, give the runloop some time to run in between changing the images. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829977/nstextfield-waits-until-the-end-of-a-loop-to-update/5830376#5830376

Comment: Otherwise, use the builtin animation support from Hagelin's answer, do performSelectorAfterDelay with varying delays, etc. All of these will let the run loop run, which means the window gets updated to reflect your changes.

Answer (score 2):

If `pictoImage` is an `UIImageView`, @Hagelin's answer is the best way to go. Now, if `pictoImage` is not an `UIImageView` object then you will have to take a different approach and that definitely is not a loop.

Set an NSTimer with a desired time interval and invoke a method that updates `pictoImage` iterating over the `tabImages`. It should be something like this :-

```
- (void)setup {
    ...

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(updatePictoImage:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];

    ...
}

- (void)updatePictoImage:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
    static int i = 0;
    if ( i > 20 ) {
        pictoImage.image = [tabImages objectAtIndex:(i % 5)];
    } else {
       [theTimer invalidate];
    }
}
```

This should update the `pictoImage` every 2 seconds with images in `tabImages`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't print *anything*.

You are overriding the contents of your `pictoImage` 20 times in a row, leaving it with the last assignment when var is 19, so it should be picto_4.png.

Also, the whole `var` declaration doesn't make much sense at all... first you set it to `0`, then you set it to `indexPath.row`, and in the loop it is completely redefined....