# How to loop an animation with some changes at each iteration?

Tags: iphone, loops, core-animation

I want my animation to loop and slow down gradually. I dont think that it is possible to use "repeats" property in this case because animation has to slow down at the end of each iteration. My plan was simple:

1) Create and initialize an animation (outside the for-loop body).

2) Create a for loop. In the body of this loop set the duration property for my animation. And start animation adding it to my view (it is explicit animation).

3) Wait for the duration time and proceed executing the loop.

I used usleep() function to wait till the animation finishes. On the next loop iteration the same animation is added and it's duration property is changed (increased to slow down the animation). Here's the code (all the code to initialize animation is above and it works fine without the following modifications):

```
for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
        // Find the duration (I simplified this part it depends on i value).
        keyframeAnim.duration = ...;
        // Add an animation.
        [self addAnimation:keyframeAnim forKey:@"loopingLongAnimation"];
        // Wait till it stops.
        usleep(keyframeAnim.duration);
    }
```

The problem is this doesn't work properly. It only plays sample animation once and stops. Looks like I missed somthing very essential to the Core Animation. Are there some more appropriate or suitable solutions for this purpose? Can i use timing curve to affect the whole looping animation not only the it's sample part?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is rendered, because rendering necessitates pumping the run loop. See my answer to [Displaying images in sequence with a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990600/displaying-images-in-sequence-with-a-loop/5990647#5990647)

I think in this case you could perhaps set a delay on each animation, equivalent to the previous animation's delay + duration, so the animations are aligned head-to-tail on the timeline.

But it would probably be better to just wire up an animation delegate that responds to the animation did stop message by starting the next, slower animation.

Both of these make your animation loop run asynchronously, so that the run loop can execute normally.