# Change UIImageView UIImage during Loop Execution

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that uses a video as a AVURLAsset and cuts the video at time intervals. I also have UIImageview IBOutlet called previewImageView that I would like for the images to change as the function is being executed. This function is called in the viewDidLoad. The previewImageView only seems to be set after the function has finished executing. My code below

```
func getImagesAtInterval(url: NSURL){

    let asset : AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: url, options: nil)
    let duration : CMTime = asset.duration
    let totalTime = Int(CMTimeGetSeconds(duration) * 1000)
    let assetGenerator : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)

    imageSet = [UIImage]()
    var value = 0

    for var i : Int = 0; i < totalTime; i+=200 {

        let time : CMTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(value), 1000)
        var imageRef : CGImageRef!
        do {
            imageRef = try assetGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Image generation failed with error \(error)")
        }
        if let image : UIImage? = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

//I would like to see the images in the previewImageView 
//change as the loop operates.
                self.previewImageView.image = image
            }
            imageSet.append(image!)
        }           
        value += 200
    }
}
```

I've tried to do as suggested in resource[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990600/displaying-images-in-sequence-with-a-loop)

Comment: UIKit delays screen updates to do them all at once control passes back to the run loop. Use `CADisplayLink` instead, which will call the method you give it on screen updates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invalidate the image for it to refresh right away.
Just call `setNeedsDisplay()` function of UIView.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) 
{
  self.previewImageView.image = image
  self.previewImageView.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, though it doesn't seem to work, perhaps i'm not giving enough time for the images to be drawn ? I want as the images are generate, that of the previewImageView will also be changing until the loop ends.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer. It should be the function setNeedsDisplay instead. Cheers.

Comment: still not working, please have a look at the updated question with the link and tell me what you think, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use `CADisplayLink` instead, which will try to synchronise with screen refreshes.

Here's some Objective-C code, I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to convert it to Swift.

```
// call this method when you want to start updates
- (void)startUpdates
{
    _displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doFrame)];
    _displayLink.frameInterval = 1;
    [_displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

// I'll let you guess
- (void)stopUpdates
{
    [_displayLink invalidate];
    _displayLink = nil;
}

// In this method, do any needed updates.
// Note that it will not necessarily be called every single frame,
// so check actual time to decide what to display
- (void)doFrame
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I converted the code to swift but it didn't seem to work. I called the startUpdating on entering the getImagesAtInterval function and the stopUpdating after the loop(outside). In the doframe I was setting previewImageView image to imageSet.last as imageSet is an array of uiimages.

Comment: That won't work. All of this happens on the same thread, so obviously if you keep hogging the CPU on the thread, nothing else happens. You need to retrieve the images and display them in doFrame

Comment: @DrPatience, if the answer helped you, feel free to up vote and/or accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by calling my getImageAtInterval method in a background thread in viewDidLoad and calling the "previewImageView.image = image" in a UIThread :)