# How to add a delay to a loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, uiimageview

Im attempting add image views to a UIView using this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <numberOfImages; i++) {
    UIImageView *image = [UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 40, 40)];
    image.image = [images objectAtIndex:i];
    [self.view addSubview:image];
}
```

This works but the problem is I would like to have a 5 second delay before it adds each image, instead it adds them all at the same time. Can anybody help me out? Thanks.

Example:

```
5 seconds = one image on screen
10 seconds = two images on screen
15 seconds = three images on screen
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying images in sequence with a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990600/displaying-images-in-sequence-with-a-loop), [Displaying multiple images serially within a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5794105)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will be more efficient to use an [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:numberOfSeconds
                                                      target:self 
                                                    selector:@selector(methodToAddImages:) 
                                                    userInfo:nil 
                                                     repeats:YES];
```

This will essentially call `methodToAddImages` repeatedly with the specified time interval. To stop this method from being called, call `[NSTimer invalidate]` (bear in mind that an invalidated timer cannot be reused, and you will need to create a new timer object in case you want to repeat this process).

Inside `methodToAddImages` you should have code to go over the array and add the images.
You can use a counter variable to track the index.

Another option (my recommendation) is to have a mutable copy of this array and add `lastObject` as a subview and then remove it from the mutable copy of your array.

You can do this by first making a mutableCopy in reversed order as shown:

```
NSMutableArray* reversedImages = [[[images reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects] mutableCopy];
```

Your methodToAddImages looks like:

```
- (void)methodToAddImages
{
    if([reversedImages lastObject] == nil)
    {
        [timer invalidate];
        return;
    }

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(40, 40, 40, 40))];
    imageView.image = [reversedImages lastObject];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    [reversedImages removeObject:[reversedImages lastObject]];
}
```

I don't know if you're using ARC or Manual Retain Release, but this answer is written assuming ARC (based on the code in your question).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [dispatch_after](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) to dispatch a block, executed asynchronously that adds the image. Example:

```
for(int i = 0; numberOfImages; i++)
{
    double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void)
    {
        UIImageView *image = [UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 40, 40)];
        image.image = [images objectAtIndex:i];
        // Update the view on the main thread:
        [self.view performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(addSubview:) withObject: image waitUntilDone: NO];
    });
}
```

Comment: Tried this out, I thought it would work but it just adds all of the images at the same time after the delay. Any ideas?

Comment: @SarabyteStudios You're right, I forgot that any view should be updated just on the main thread. So I edited the last line of code in the block to make sure that the method to add the subview gets executed on the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

Separate your code into a function, and call via `NSTimer`.

```
for (int i = 0; numberOfImages; i++) {
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(showImage)
                                                    userInfo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] 
                                                     repeats:NO];
```

And then your function:

```
-(void) showImage:(NSTimer*)timer {
      //do your action, using
      NSNumber *i = timer.userInfo;

      //Insert relevant code here

      if (!done)
          NSTimer *newTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(showImage)
                                                    userInfo:[NSNumber numberWithInt: i.intValue+1]
                                                     repeats:NO];
  }
}
```

`userInfo` is a convenient way of passing parameters to functions that you need to call (but they do have to be Objects). Also, by using `repeats:NO`, you don't have to worry about invalidating the timer, and there's no risk of leaving timer running in memory.

Comment: Since you're using showImage: and incrementing the intValue, seems like the initial loop is redundant here. This technique works without it.

Comment: Also "selector:@selector(showImage)" should actually be "selector:@selector(showImage:)"

Answer (score 2):

also this is best option. Try this

```
 [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5.0]];
```

Comment: Could you explain exactly why it's better to follow your way of implementing time delay, please ?

Comment: @XLE_22  SRunLoop is better because it allows the `NSRunLoop` to respond to events while you wait.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better off with an animation

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++)
{
    // Retrieve the image
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 40, 40)];
    image.image = [images objectAtIndex:i];

    // Add with alpha 0
    image.alpha = 0.0;
    [self.view addSubview:image];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:5.0*i options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
        // Fade in with delay
        image.alpha = 1.0;
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Not exactly what you asked for, since all the views will be added immediately, and then faded-in, but I feel that you're actually trying to achieve that, like some sort of stacking of images, right?

In fact, if you plan on removing the previous image, you can do it in the completion block, like this:

```
UIImageView *imagePrevious = nil;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++)
{
    // Retrieve the image
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 40, 40)];
    image.image = [images objectAtIndex:i];

    // Add with alpha 0
    image.alpha = 0.0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:5.0*i options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
        // Add and fade in with delay
        [self.view addSubview:image];
        image.alpha = 1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        if (finished && imagePrevious)
        {
            [imagePrevious removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }];

    imagePrevious = image;
}
```

Comment: This won't create a 5 sec time interval though

Comment: @Rakesh I wrote the delay to be variable (`5.0*i`), actually.

Comment: oops.. i read it as 0.2*i. never mind. +1 for the 'not the obvious' solution :)

Comment: I think I actually was editing the question while you commented, prior to that I added 0.2 to test on my simulator.

Comment: Oh. All right. I was actually thinking how I saw it different. :)