# Add a delay to a for loop in swift

Tags: ios, for-loop, delay, nstimer, swift3

I have a coding 'issue'.

I have a label, which text I want to change dynamically every 2 seconds.
I've done the following:

```
// WELCOME STRING ARRAY
let welcomeContainer:[String] = ["Welcome","Benvenuti","Bienvenue","Willkommen","üdvözlet","Dobrodošli","добро пожаловать","Witajcie","Bienvenido","Ласкаво просимо","Vitajte","欢迎你来"]
```

and then, rather than using a `timerwithinterval` (which seemed to be too much for this simple task), I tried with the `delay` method in my function inside `for` loop:

```
func welcomeLabelChange() {
for i in 0..<welcomeContainer.count {
    welcomeLabel.text = welcomeContainer[i]
    delay(delay: 2.0, closure: {})
}
```

Unfortunately it's entirely skipping the delay... the for loop is executed instantly and just the last text in the array is displayed.
What am I doing wrong?

I found this [OBJ-C answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731840/how-to-add-a-delay-to-a-loop), but it's suggesting an (old) `NSTimer` implementation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can also use this function to delay something

```
//MARK: Delay func 

func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(
        deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: closure)
}
```

and usage is :

```
        delay(2)  //Here you put time you want to delay
{
            //your delayed code
        }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you :)

Comment: This doesn't work. All items in the loop will get called immediately (but after a 2 second delay).

Comment: Ingenious answer!

Answer (score 7):

define those variables

```
var i = 0
let timer : Timer?
```

Place this timer in your view did load or wherever you want to start the label change

```
   timer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector:#selector(YourViewController.changeText), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

and implement this method:

```
func changeText(){
    if i>=welcomeContainer.count {
        i = 0
    }

    welcomeLabel.text = welcomeContainer[i]
    i += 1
}
```

when you want to stop it or change the view controller dont forget to call

```
timer.invalidate()
```

Comment: Thanks @ben your suggestion is exactly what I wanted to do. On the other hand I wanted to explore the "delay" function rather than a timer! But your's works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

You can add sleep function

```
for i in 0..<welcomeContainer.count {
    welcomeLabel.text = welcomeContainer[i]
    sleep(2) // or sleep(UInt32(0.5)) if you need Double
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep it all inline you can do this:

```
var loop: ((Int) -> Void)!
loop = { [weak self] count in
  guard count > 0 else { return }
  //Do your stuff
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    loop(count - 1)
  }
}
loop(10) //However many loops you want
```

Answer (score 2):

With `Timer`, you should be careful to call `invalidate` of the `Timer` in `viewDidDisappear` or else you may not release the view controller.

Alternatively, you can use a GCD dispatch timer, in which you completely eliminate the strong reference cycle by using `[weak self]` pattern:

```
@IBOutlet weak var welcomeLabel: UILabel!

var timer: DispatchSourceTimer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let welcomeStrings = ["Welcome", "Benvenuti", "Bienvenue", "Willkommen", "üdvözlet", "Dobrodošli", "добро пожаловать", "Witajcie", "Bienvenido", "Ласкаво просимо", "Vitajte", "欢迎你来"]
    var index = welcomeStrings.startIndex
    timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: .main)
    timer.scheduleRepeating(deadline: .now(), interval: .seconds(2))
    timer.setEventHandler { [weak self] in
        self?.welcomeLabel.text = welcomeStrings[index]
        index = index.advanced(by: 1)
        if index == welcomeStrings.endIndex {
            index = welcomeStrings.startIndex // if you really want to stop the timer and not have this repeat, call self?.timer.cancel()
        }
    }
    timer.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Marked answer doesn't delay loop iterations and you still get just the last value in the label.text.

You can solve it like this:

```
func showWelcome(_ iteration: Int = 0) {
    let i = iteration>=self.welcomeContainer.count ? 0 : iteration
    let message = self.welcomeContainer[i]
    self.delay(2){
        self.welcomeLabel.text = message
        return self.showWelcome(i + 1)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    showWelcome()
```